# TTask slower than TThread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have below two methods of multi-threading code doing the same job.

TTask:

```
const
  MaxThreadCount = 80;

procedure TWorkerTask.Update;
var
  aTasks  : array of ITask;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Stopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  SetLength(aTasks, MaxThreadCount);
  for I := Low(aTasks) to High(aTasks) do begin
    aTasks[I] := TTask.Create( procedure
    begin
      Writeln('Thread ', TTask.CurrentTask.Id, ' Stared');
      Sleep(5000);
      Writeln('Thread ', TTask.CurrentTask.Id, ' Finshed');
    end);
    aTasks[I].Start;
  end;
  TTask.WaitForAll(aTasks);
  Elapsed := Stopwatch.Elapsed;
  Writeln('Done in ', Round(Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
end;
```

Output e.g `Done in 29`

TThread:

```
const
  MaxThreadCount = 80;

procedure TWorker.Execute;
begin
  Writeln('Thread ', ThreadID, ' Stared');
  Sleep(5000);
  Writeln('Thread ', ThreadID, ' Finshed');
end;

....

var
  Workers   : array of TWorker;
  I         : Integer;
  Stopwatch : TStopwatch;
  Elapsed   : TTimeSpan;  
begin
  SetLength(Workers, MaxThreadCount);
  for I := Low(Workers) to High(Workers) do begin
    Workers[I] := TWorker.Create;
    Workers[I].Start;
  end;
  for I := Low(Workers) to High(Workers) do
    Workers[I].WaitFor;
  Elapsed := Stopwatch.Elapsed;
  Writeln('Done ', Round(Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
```

Output e.g `Done 8`

Q: Why the [TTask](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Threading.TTask) is extremely slower than the [TThread](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread) class on the above method? Is there a way to speed it up to get similar result?

Comment: Your output does not match your code.  What is the *actual* output?

Comment: @RemyLebeau outputs edited

Comment: @RepeatUntil What's the point of coding `Writeln('Thread ', ThreadID, ' Stared');` etc., if you're not going to use it? Note: The output of those lines can be extremely important to help you understand what's happening (especially if you include time-stamps in your output).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because your threads and tasks do no work.

You have more threads than processors. In the version using threads, you can create one thread per task and although the processors are oversubscribed, that doesn't matter because the threads are sleeping.

In the task based version there is, typically, one thread per processor. So not all tasks can run simultaneously.

Were you to replace the sleep with busy work running the CPU at full utilisation then you would see that both versions performed similarly. Indeed I would expect the task based version to be better since it would not oversubscribe the processors.

Comment: Similarly? Are you sure? I don't know how that `TTask` implementation looks like (from what you described it seems it distributes work by itself according to CPU cores), but creating 80 threads is a real overhead (even if context switching should be efficient). If Delphi implemented native thread pool, they would go better, but as far as I know, they don't.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Overhead over 80 threads is trivial compared to 5s sleep.

Comment: I believe in fair context switching but in real, what's the real usage of having 80 threads in paralel other than server (except some heavy computing which might be distributed to many machines)? In that case I would think about native thread pool API implementation or a queue rather than naive creating so many threads. Definitely not thinking whether `TTask` brings a performance advantage. Of course sleeping is the issue here (hence the benchmark is incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

Each task does not necessarily mean 1 thread. The delphi tasks system saves resources, and even monitors CPU usage to decide whether to create more threads or not. Particularly I also find the task slow, and to avoid this slowness, when I need to use task I simply create a threadpool for each task, so it will have the same performance as a simple TThread because that way you will ensure that each task will run on own thread.

You can try something like this:

```
TTask.Run(
  procedure()
  begin
  end, TThreadPool.Create);
```